Why does it take so long to stop the rotor of a helicopter after landing?
Every time I see a helicopter (EC135 or the like) land on a hospital helipad next to my workplace, I wonder why there's maybe a minute? of waiting for the rotor to slowly spool down before offloading the patient can begin. I'm sure that a minute can make a real difference to someone requiring urgent transport to a hospital. I would thus assume that ideally, the crew would love to just engage the mother of all rotor brakes at the moment of touchdown and get the patient out five seconds later. (This is an exaggeration, of course five seconds are an unattainable ideal, meant just to illustrate the point.)
From an EC135 manual I understand that the rotor brake can only be used at low RPM, after the rotor has slowed down sufficiently on its own, which seems to be what takes the longest. Being an engineer myself, I don't think that those helicopters were designed by idiots. There clearly must be a good reason why helicopters able to stop the rotor in 10-20 seconds aren't common.

Given that it seems to me that the rotor is spun down with the blades near zero AoA, why not pitch them to a high-drag state instead to waste energy quickly? Perhaps set them to negative AoA to pump lots of air upwards, or feather them?
Would a rotor brake able to soak up all the energy quickly enough be unacceptably heavy? Or would the torque break the rotor shaft?
Is the medevac helicopter market (presumably the only one that would care about quick offloading) just too small to pay for designing and certifying a dedicated solution? (Are the potentially saved human lives not worth the paperwork?)


Momentum is high (and aviation is made by light as possible objects, so also not more strong then necessary), but also the hydraulic, cooling need an engine (and without APU, you need it running at low speed). -- But you do not need to stop rotors to enter/exit an helicopter: in fact if you are not sure on the capability of the terrain to keep the load of the heli, you keep the engine up.

Why wouldn't the pilot leave the rotor spinning and pull up on the collective a little to flex the blades upwards, but not enough to lift the aircraft off the ground, and offload the patient straight away?

Be glad one has all that rotor momentum if the engine fails and you need to land.

One minute is pretty much insignificant in patient transportation. Critical is the time to get the emergency people to the patient, to stabilise him so he would be able to survive the transport. Once the bleeding is stopped, the heart beating again, and the first drugs and intubation in the patient, you're in no rush. You can't do a cardiac massage while the ambulance is driving, or the heli flying. The medics are, in both cases, strapped to their seats, for good reason.

@Karl Surely there are also cases where the patient needs an urgent operation to survive; perhaps to stop some bad internal bleeding or something. I clearly know nothing about emergency medicine so I can't quantify how often it happens, but it just sounds unlikely that everyone can be stabilized already before reaching the hospital.

@TooTea It's very modern for mislead statisticans to do the math (often correctly) and come up with a study that says e.g. a one minute reduction in flight time will save so-and-so many hundreds of lifes worldwide. That's cargo-cult science, because the predicted improvement is significantly smaller than the uncertainty in predicting the future survival rate of medevac passengers.

@Karl I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying I'm making stuff up or trying to manipulate someone? I have openly stated that I don't have the data, do you? For all I know, such a really urgent situation could occur in 50% of the cases or in 1% of the cases, and the conclusion would be very different depending on that. If you know for sure it's the latter and thus it makes no sense at all to optimize for these situations, please post it as an answer.

@TooTea No, and I don't have data either. I'm saying that a reduction of one minute in typically one hour between accident and OR table will only matter at all for a smaller fraction of the cases, and even there it will only be statistically significant if you go for large numbers. There will be far better ways to spend money, to save a minute before patient transportation, where all patients profit, and much more. You can only spend a dollar once. ;)

Are the medical staff on the helicopter during spin down not doing anything with the casualty at all to get them ready for transfer out or are they reduced to retying their shoelaces during that idle time?

@civitas If I knew, I wouldn't have asked this question. If you know that the wait never matters, please post that as a proper answer.

"set them to negative AoA to pump lots of air upwards" - you risk sucking debris and people upwards.

@RobertDiGiovanni rotor momentum will not keep a helicopter flying for long...

@jpe61 my understanding is a helicopter can autorotate, with enough momentum to briefly hover before landing.

@TooTea Regarding urgent operation? It depends. For critical trauma cases, at least some services are just training the air ambulance doctors to perform the operations. There's at least a couple of cases of air ambulance doctors performing open heart surgery in a street to stabilize someone. Yes, its not ideal from an infection point of view, but that can be treated afterwards, if it happens.

yes @RobertDiGiovanni, a very brief moment.

@user1937198 Classical M.A.S.H stuff ;)

A minute isn't that long a time. Arranging the medevac flight plus the flight itself will typically take about 1 hour in one of the best healthcare systems. Urban medevac cycle times can be shorter, with 10-minute dispatch, but the most critical time is about reaching the patient.
Braking the rotor mechanically will convert its momentum into torque against the helicopter. That can cause the helicopter to skip on the ground, especially if it has just landed and still doesn't have its whole weight on the skids. Regular helicopter rotor brakes are mostly meant to prevent accidents from wind-induced spin. Additionally, conventional drivetrains are built for relatively moderate stress.
The only way to avoid the torque problem is to go coaxial or counter-rotating like the Chinook. Then the torque from the two rotors cancels out, and the energy can be absorbed by brakes.
If one was designing for medevac in a "cost no object" environment, they might go coaxial anyway, due to smaller rotor diameter and better control, which can accelerate missions by more than a minute due to easier or better-positioned landings.
Coaxial drivetrains are highly stressed to begin with, as they have to absorb the assymmetry in lateral forces from the two rotors, requiring oversized high-strength steel parts, driving up their cost and weight. Fast rotor brakes would add more weight, but at least the rest of the high-stress drivetrain is already a sunk cost.
Ultimately, you can put a price on the human life, and aviation and medical industries have it in the 5-10 million range - higher than most. If a minute makes a 0.1% difference, it's worth $10k per medevac under that high evaluation.
A custom coaxial helicopter with rotor brakes will be on the upper side of the price range, but an extra million would pay off over 100 missions. Another cost would be noise: coaxials cannot be made as quiet as conventional designs with fenestrons or NOTAR.

Depends how you define 'best' health systems. Urban and rural medical helicopter setups have very different targets. Norway is a rural setup, supporting urgent but not-super critical medivac where the roads aren't good enough and distances too far. Compare this to the London Urban air ambulance which has a target response time of roughly 10 minutes each direction within its operational area, but only takes highest critical cases where 15 minutes for a road ambulance to arrive would be too long/the patient needs to be in front of a doctor in under 15 minutes.

One thing with the time to reach the patient: Whilst patient unload has to wait for the rotors to stop, do they have to wait for the rotors to stop in the field before the crew in the helicopter disembark? Since that would mean that the rotor stopping time doesn't apply to that critical time to reach the patient. And needing the couple of minutes for patient unload is mitigated by stabilization by the crew prior to loading.

@user1937198 Trained crews are normally permitted to exit a helicopter with the rotors still spinning. Military medevac is done with the rotor spinning. But I'm not sure on civilian procedure - there's more equipment involved, and it's important that nothing is flapping that could be hit by the rotor.

"it's important that nothing is flapping that could be hit by the rotor"  Didn't think of that!  Very critical point

@Therac The medics don't walk out of the helicopter in a white coat, with a stethoscope around their neck. ;)

The survival rate of medevac patients probably has a global year-to year variation in the 10% range. Working on .1% improvements is a waste of time and money, and probably lifes of helicopter crews in this case, with new technology that's not really a clear improvement.

@Karl Are you sure about those numbers? There are hundreds or thousands of such flights a year in my small EU country. There's got to be at least hundreds of thousands of such flights worldwide. That should me more than enough for decent statistics.

@TooTea Yes, but a lot of air ambulance (whether helicopter or small plane) trips are not for trauma/rescue situations but for transport between hospitals or other situations where the extra speed is considered important but it isn't "every second counts". And arguably overused in many of the non-trauma situations due to high profits for the companies in that business (which is quite different from the emergency trauma situations, which are often handled by govt. or non-profits) - I remember reading a book about the high cost of healthcare that went into that topic quite extensively.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's largely US-specific, due to the combination of insurance and litigation. If you use air ambulance when you didn't have to, you just bill the insurance. But if you don't and the patient dies in transit, even if it wouldn't have helped, you're on the hook for lawsuits. So - "they pay, we fly".

Your question makes a lot of sense from a theoretical perspective and I have no good answers for the technical questions like whether a supplemental brake is possible because that's not the sort of engineering I do.
I do have experience both as an engineer and as a first responder, and I have worked for a company that provides this service in the US.
These flights are extremely expensive as it is, because they meet the convergence of some already-strict standards and requirements.
For instance, you pretty much need a turbine helicopter because of the weight of (normally) 2 pilots, 2 care providers, 1 patient, and a lot of heavy medical equipment. Adding more cost to the helicopter makes the equation much harder. Ultimately, however priceless we (as a society) feel the cost of life is, we simply cannot endure infinite expense for everyone who needs it.
Another answer speaks to the response time of the helicopter. Keep in mind that emergency medicine in the field takes a shockingly long period of time. I have spent the better part of an hour clearing a landing site for a helicopter. Just making the decision to have the flight scheduled can take tens of minutes. If the patient was going to die in the time it took the rotors to spin down, that's unfortunate, but it's also how these things go.
Another axiom of first responders is this: never add to the body count. Everyone who is involved is a person with a family and this is their job (or they are a volunteer). The needs of the one person, who had an unfortunate problem like a car accident, cannot put everyone involved at unreasonable risk. Everyone involved is comfortable waiting for the rotors to spin down safely and naturally because they want to live. Many of them probably know someone firsthand who didn't, and didn't.

This is a fantastically interesting real-world actual-experience economic answer, thanks!  one note, as everyone has explained, there is a plain technical reason you can't brake a helicopter blade: it will make the blades (or perhaps the whole helicopter) destroy itself in to shards due to the torque, or at best, will "skip around" (all of which options would kill a few/many people) - - as has been explained in the other answers. (Of course, any unrealistic engineering challenge can be overcome with unrealistic money, but that is the "reason".)

@Fattie It sounds unrealistic that the blades would shatter if they were to be slowed down any faster than they currently are. The blades are able to carry several metric tons of load in flight and they certainly weigh at least an order of magnitude less than that, so they should survive a couple of g's of deceleration just fine. Their attachment to the rotor hub is likely a different story, since that's designed to handle the normal load acting in a very different direction so it might well be a bit too weak in the plane of the rotor, plus there's the leverage of a very long blade.

Time taken to make the decision is service and context specific. For a dedicated urban air ambulance service, 10 minutes to decide would be pointlessly paralyzing, with a conventional road ambulance already being most of the way there/already at the scene. 1 hour to helicopter landing would already have the patient in a hospital. But that's a very different service and set of goals when the entire purpose of the service is handing the patients who will die if not in front of a doctor in under 15 minutes vs handling patients who are multiple hours drive from a hospital.

@TooTea, for sure, that's possible, as I said "something bad would happen" - one expert below predicts the chopper overall may "skip" around (ie: killing everyone nearby!)

@user1937198 irrelevant. Most helicopter ambulance services don't work in urban centers where response times for regular ambulances are short AND there are few is any places for them to land. E.g. where I live the nearest place to land an helicopter would be a farm field about a 20 minute walk away, a field that usually has cows in it. By law an ambulance has to be at the scene after it's called within 15 minutes (though they often don't make that for lack of vehicles and crews). 

 Helipcopters, when called, are usually for transport to specialist clinics (like burn units) further away where the helicopter can get there much faster than the ambulance despite the longer response times. So the vehicle gets there first, calls for the helicopter, and THEN the helicopter takes to the air

@jwenting Whilst most don't, those that do operate within urban areas exist, with the London Air Ambulance being one of the most extreme optimized cases, focused entirely critical trauma response within an urban area of less than 10 minutes flight time in radius. For that specific example, they have a setup that is supposed to take roughly 5 minutes to takeoff. Including a setup for listening in on ambulance dispatchers so they can make the call to dispatch the helicopter, before an ambulance arrives at the scene.

And 'an ambulance has to be at the scene in 15 minutes', and 'the patient is in front of a doctor qualified to perform surgery in 15 minutes' are two very different things. Which matters for things like if a patient is bleeding out from a stab wound.

If you were building a helicopter specifically for medivac and price was no object, there's nothing stopping you from doing it, but, the price will be a lot of weight, both for a brake large enough to stop the rotor from operating RPM, and the structural requirements for the rotor system itself to withstand the lead-direction bending loads on the blade roots plus the torque reaction at the top of the mast between the brake and rotor and brake and transmission, from applying heavy braking at high speed, that they don't normally have to withstand.
Once you add that sort of weight to an existing design, the merry-go-round starts because you lost some performance and need more power because of the ballast created by this very special feature, which needs more structure and more fuel, which needs more power, which needs...
So you have a helicopter that is quite a bit heavier, likely with a significant performance hit, saddled with a feature that nobody else in the industry wants, so it won't sell.

Okay, so basically an "all of the above" kind of answer. Regarding blade bending and torque limits, it feels to me that there should be plenty of headroom because spinning the rotor up before takeoff seems to be much quicker than stopping it after landing. Is there something making those two processes not symmetric?

I'm no expert on this, but from what little I've read/understand, I think a key issue is that the rotor is designed to basically spin freely in order to have even a tiny hope of being able to land safely in an engine-out situation. So the engine pushes the rotor in one direction and the rotor spins freely in that direction. But to slow it down you need either a large friction brake = weight + heat generated + wear & tear on rotor parts, etc., or some way to forcibly slow the rotor using the engine - but that goes against letting it run free.

@TooTea the spin up on start doesn't apply anything like the loads that would be applied (in the other direction) if you wanted to slow the rotor down quickly from the green arc.

@too re action being reversable, try spinning up a length of rope with your arm and then stop. As you accelerate the blades the centrifugal forces are pulling them straighter, but bringing them to a stop risks them getting all twisted as they unload. That said, pretty sure some ship based helicopters do have a blade brake to make deck operations easier, but those birds need robust blades to handle folding anyway.

"some way to forcibly slow the rotor using the engine - but that goes against letting it run free." - a gearbox? Depending on how the one-way linkage works, integrating a mechanism to switch it to both ways might be the easiest option.

@TooTea At least in my experience with helicopters, it takes a relatively long time for them to spin up, too, though I'm not sure how much of this is due to nearly all of the ones I've seen being turbine-powered vs. actual design requirements of the rotors. Starting up a turbofan engine on a fixed-wing aircraft also usually takes a while.

@JohnDvorak a gearbox is a brake.  torque is torque.  You can't beat physics in a non-Star Trek universe.

@reirab Fair point, but an EC135 can apparently take off about 70 seconds after engine start and I'm not sure the rotor was steadily accelerating all that time, so it feels like getting the reverse done in at most a minute should be technically feasible.

@JohnDvorak Helicopters typically use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprag_clutch to connect the transmission to the rotors, so that if the engine or transmission seizes, the rotor will still be able to autorotate. And thats not a mechanism that can really be made two ways without undermining the simplicity and reliability which is a key feature.

Addressing this subquestion that the other answers haven't included yet:

Given that it seems to me that the rotor is spun down with the blades near zero AoA, why not pitch them to a high-drag state instead to waste energy quickly? Perhaps set them to negative AoA to pump lots of air upwards, or feather them?

Unlike a mechanical brake on the axis, this air braking wouldn't generate extra torque on the helicopter. From physics perspective it is very feasible and could slow down the rotor faster.
However the mechanical design of most helicopters limits the collective movement to a range of about 0° to 20-40° (some models less, some models more). Thus there is no setting that would increase drag without creating lift. Extra lift would increase the risk of sideways movement or spinning due to motor braking torque and wind conditions.
Some helicopters like Westland Lynx do have negative collective, which is mostly used for landings on ship decks. Typically in such a scenario you would keep the rotor spinning until the helicopter can be secured by other means. Supporting negative collective requires multiple design changes:

More movement range in control rods and swashplate
Larger rotor clearance on the body, as the blades are deflected downwards
Rotor head bearings that can handle high axial forces in both directions

If the helicopter has the feature, I don't think there is anything that would stop you from using negative collective for ground landings. It's not a standard procedure and could result in increased wear.
On the Lynx the maximum negative pitch is about 2 degrees. Near 0 degrees airfoil drag increases slowly. Typically at +-5° the drag coefficient is about double of what it is at 0°. On the Lynx, using maximum negative pitch would probably increase the drag by at most 25%, so you wouldn't really save much time at all.
Turning the blades sideways (90° pitch) would greatly increase the drag and result in a rapid stop. But moving from the nearly 0° pitch at the moment of landing to this perpendicular configuration would temporarily cause large forces, again increasing the risk of movement on the landing pad.

Thanks, this also answers my unstated sub-question of "why can't helicopters "flare" the rotor like a fixed-wing landing" (gradually decreasing rotor RPM while in air and increasing collective so that there's as little excess momentum in the rotor at touchdown as possible) instead of using a giant constant-speed prop". Yeah, I obviously don't know anything about rotorcraft.

@TooTea I think technically they could, as that is kind of what you do in an autorotation landing if the propeller RPM starts to drop. But then you have much less control over altitude, because changing the motor speed takes time.

There is no need.
For pickup, helicopters can and do land within 1 meter of the patient (sorry for German).
Once inside the helicopter, the patient is already under medical care, so they should be out of the every-second-counts status in most cases.
I do see videos where medical personnel walks under a moving rotor, though this is on pickup, not on transfer into the hospital.

+1: rotor tilt can be neutral, i.e. rotor can turn with very limited air movement. The 1-minute delay between touchdown and people going out of the helicopter may be related not to rotor spinning, but to remove whatever leashes were installed on injured people for the flight phase.

You have a point, so yes, the medics do walk under the rotor. I'm less sure if it's safe for a patient, who might have tubes and devices attached to them, which could be pulled or pushed around by rotor wash.
